# php multibyte string acessing via key [$i]

Tags: php

there is a string `$string = "öşğüçı";`   pay attention to the last one which is not i 
when I want to print first char by `echo $string[0]`   it prints nothing.. I know they are multibyte ones.. though printing first character can be accomplished by

`echo $string[0].$string[1]`  but that is not what I want.. the question is

how can I make the obove mentioned issue just to program in a way below

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($string); $i++)
   echo $string[$i] . " ";
```

and it will print the following

```
ö ş ğ ü ç ı
```

masters of php please help...

Answer (score 4):

to split a string into characters

```
$string = "öşğüçı";
preg_match_all('/./u', $string, $m);
$chars = $m[0];
```

note the "u" flag in the regular expression

Comment: thx for the alternative way. but I dont want an array retuned.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
// inform the browser you are sending text encoded with utf-8
header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");

// if you're using a literal string make sure the file 
// is saved using utf-8 as encoding
// or if you're getting it from another source make sure 
// you get it in utf-8
$string = "öşğüçı";

// if you do not have your string in utf-8
// you need to find out the actual encoding
// and use "iconv" to convert it to utf-8

// process the string using the mb_* functions 
// knowing that it is encoded in utf-8 at this point
$encoding = "UTF-8";
for($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($string, $encoding); $i++) {
   echo mb_substr($string, $i, 1, $encoding);
}
```

*Of course if you prefer another encoding (but I wouldn't see why; maybe just utf-16) you can substitute each instance of "utf-8" from above with your desired encoding and read and use accordingly.*

---

Example for UTF-16 output (file/input is encoded in UTF-8)

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-16");
$string = "öşğüçı";
$string = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-16", $string);
$encoding = "UTF-16";
for($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($string, $encoding); $i++) {
   echo mb_substr($string, $i, 1, $encoding);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot handle multi-byte strings in this way in PHP. If it's a fixed-length encoding, where every character takes up, say, two bytes, you can simply take two bytes at a time. If it's a variable-length encoding like UTF-8 though, you will need to use [`mb_substr`](http://www.php.net/mb_substr) and [`mb_strlen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php).

May I recommend [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/), which explains this in more detail.

Comment: thak you. you get me right. I tried same stuff in python. it works well. Will this problem be solved in php in the future. cause I am asking this for the algorithms written for plain texts where every char acessed with a variable key.??

Comment: @nurmurat Who knows? :) AFAIK PHP 6 is supposed to have Unicode support, but this has been vaporware for years now.

Answer (score 0):

Use [iconv_substr](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv-substr.php) or [mb_substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) to get character and `iconv_strlen` or `mb_strlen` to get size of string.